# Botón no llama método onClickListener

Tags: java, android

Soy nuevo programando en Android y estoy tratando de guardar la información en una bd externa con los datos registrados en el Main5Activity, hago llamado al botón (btnrd) con un setOnClickListener, es decir al momento de dar click en dicho botón se ejecute los comandos dados en este código,  sin embargo al dar click al botón registrar diezmo no hace nada ¿a qué se debe esto?, ayuda por favor.

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener   {

    private static final String TAG = "Main5Activity";
    private EditText nd, date, dbruto, veintiuno, subt1, descuento5, subt2, descuento2, subt3, descuento1, tdescuento, dtotal;
    TextView txtBienvenido;
    RequestQueue rq;
    JsonRequest jrq;
    Button rdiezmo;

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener nDateSetListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        rdiezmo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrd);
        rdiezmo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registrar_diezmo();
            }
        });
        date=findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Main5Activity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        nDateSetListener,
                        year,month,day);
                        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                        dialog.show();
            }
        });

        nDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month +1;
                Log.d(TAG,"onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: "+ year + "-"+month+"-"+day);
                String ndate = year + "-"+month+"-"+day;
                date.setText(ndate);
            }
        };

        txtBienvenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbienvenido);
        txtBienvenido.setText("¡Por favor! Ingrese los datos");
        nd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtndom);
        dbruto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdbruto);
        String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
        dbruto.setText(dato);
        veintiuno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtd21);
        subt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txts1);
        descuento5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc5);
        subt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txts2);
        descuento2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc2);
        subt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txts3);
        descuento1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc1);
        tdescuento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdesc);
        dtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdiezmob);
        findViewById(R.id.btncd).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnrd).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btncd:
                //Calcula descuento 21%
                float v21 = Float.parseFloat((dbruto.getText().toString()));
                float d21 = (v21 * 21)/100;
                String r1 = String.valueOf((double) d21);
                veintiuno.setText(String.valueOf(r1));

                //Calcula subtotal 1
                float s1 = v21 - d21;
                String r2 = String.valueOf((double) s1);
                subt1.setText(String.valueOf(r2));

                //Calcula descuento 5%
                float d5 = (s1*5)/100;
                String r3 = String.valueOf((double) d5);
                descuento5.setText(String.valueOf(r3));

                //Calcula subtotal 2
                float s2 = s1 - d5;
                String r4 = String.valueOf((double) s2);
                subt2.setText(String.valueOf(r4));

                //Calcula descuento 2%
                float d2 = (s2*2)/100;
                String r5 = String.valueOf((double) d2);
                descuento2.setText(String.valueOf(r5));

                //Calcula subtotal 3
                float s3 = s2 - d2;
                String r6 = String.valueOf((double) s3);
                subt3.setText(String.valueOf(r6));

                //Calcula descuento 1%
                float d1 = (s3*1)/100;
                String r7 = String.valueOf((double) d1);
                descuento1.setText(String.valueOf(r7));

                //Calcula total descuento
                float tdesc = d21 + d5 + d2 + d1;
                String r8 = String.valueOf((double) tdesc);
                tdescuento.setText(String.valueOf(r8));

                //Calcula diezmo neto
                float dneto = s3-d1;
                String r9 = String.valueOf((double) dneto);
                dtotal.setText(String.valueOf(r9));

                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo registrar los datos" + error.toString() + dtotal.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha registrado los datos correctamente" + dtotal.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        limpiarRegistros();
    }

    void limpiarRegistros() {
        nd.setText("");
        dbruto.setText("");
        veintiuno.setText("");
        subt1.setText("");
        descuento5.setText("");
        subt2.setText("");
        descuento2.setText("");
        subt3.setText("");
        descuento1.setText("");
        tdescuento.setText("");
        dtotal.setText("");
    }
    void registrar_diezmo(){
        String url =
                "https://xxxx.com/diezmo.php?num_dom=" +nd.getText().toString() + "&fecha=" +date.getText().toString()+
                "&dbru=" +dbruto.getText().toString()+ "&subt1="+dbruto.getText().toString()+ "&desc21"+ veintiuno.getText().toString()+ "&subt2="+ subt1.getText().toString()+
                        "&desc5="+ descuento5.getText().toString()+ "&subt3="+ subt2.getText().toString()+"&desc2="+descuento2.getText().toString()+
                        "&subt4="+ subt3.getText().toString()+ "&desc1="+descuento1.getText().toString()+ "&subt5="+descuento1.getText().toString()+
                        "&tdesc="+ tdescuento.getText().toString()+ "&dneto="+dtotal.getText().toString();

        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
        rq.add(jrq);
    }
}
```

activity_main5.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ic_launcher_background2"
        tools:context="com.example.josue.login.Main5Activity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtbienvenido"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.014" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview15"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.044"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtndom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:hint="Escuela Dominical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview14"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.166" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Seleccione la Fecha"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.149" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dbruto"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.248" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtdbruto"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.237" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="@string/desc21"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.103"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.317" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtd21"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.587"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.301" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subt1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.376" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txts1"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.581"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc5"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.461" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desc5"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.57"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.444" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subt2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txts2"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.562"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.521" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.594" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desc2"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.562"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.594" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subt3"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.664" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txts3"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.557"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.669" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.758" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desc1"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.547"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tdesc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.026"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.868" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtdesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Total Descuento"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dneto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.021"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.921" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtdiezmob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Total a Pagar"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.925" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:text="@string/btncdiezmo"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.221"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnrd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:text="@string/btnrdiezmo"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.819"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Al dar click en el botón registrar diezmo este no hace nada, en el logcat no me muestra ninguna acción ejecutada al presionar dicho botón.

Comment: imprime la url que formas antes de realizar la peticion

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Elenasys, recuerda que soy nuevo programando en Android, me podrías ilustrar cómo hago esto?.

Comment: Claro que si Jair , agrega al final de tu método registrar_diezmo() : Log.i("URL", "Url de petición" +url);  y revisa el LogCat que url se imprime, puedes agregarla a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realice unos cambios al código, gracias a @Elenasys pude buscar como implementar el código, tenía un error en el llamado del botón btnrd ya que este no era llamado en ningún momento, ingrese la información dentro del switch y me funcionó:

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener   {

    private static final String TAG = "Main5Activity";
    private EditText nd, date, dbruto, veintiuno, subt1, descuento5, subt2, descuento2, subt3, descuento1, tdescuento, dtotal;
    private RequestQueue rq;
    private JsonRequest jrq;
    private Button rdiezmo;

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener nDateSetListener;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rdiezmo = findViewById(R.id.btnrd);
        date=findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day=calendar.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Main5Activity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        nDateSetListener,
                        year,month,day);
                Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        nDateSetListener = new
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                        month = month +1;
                        Log.d(TAG,"onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: "+ year +"-"+month+"-"+day);
                        String ndate = year + "-"+month+"-"+day;
                        date.setText(ndate);
                    }
                };
        TextView txtBienvenido = findViewById(R.id.txtbienvenido);
        txtBienvenido.setText("¡Por favor! Ingrese los datos");
        nd = findViewById(R.id.txtndom);
        dbruto = findViewById(R.id.txtdbruto);
        String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
        dbruto.setText(dato);
        veintiuno = findViewById(R.id.txtd21);
        subt1 = findViewById(R.id.txts1);
        descuento5 = findViewById(R.id.desc5);
        subt2 = findViewById(R.id.txts2);
        descuento2 = findViewById(R.id.desc2);
        subt3 = findViewById(R.id.txts3);
        descuento1 = findViewById(R.id.desc1);
        tdescuento = findViewById(R.id.txtdesc);
        dtotal = findViewById(R.id.txtdiezmob);
        findViewById(R.id.btncd).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnrd).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btncd:
                //Calcula descuento 21%
                float v21 = Float.parseFloat
                ((dbruto.getText().toString()));
                float d21 = (v21 * 21)/100;
                String r1 = String.valueOf((double) d21);
                veintiuno.setText((r1));

                //Calcula subtotal 1
                float s1 = v21 - d21;
                String r2 = String.valueOf((double) s1);
                subt1.setText((r2));

                //Calcula descuento 5%
                float d5 = (s1*5)/100;
                String r3 = String.valueOf((double) d5);
                descuento5.setText((r3));

                //Calcula subtotal 2
                float s2 = s1 - d5;
                String r4 = String.valueOf((double) s2);
                subt2.setText((r4));

                //Calcula descuento 2%
                float d2 = (s2*2)/100;
                String r5 = String.valueOf((double) d2);
                descuento2.setText((r5));

                //Calcula subtotal 3
                float s3 = s2 - d2;
                String r6 = String.valueOf((double) s3);
                subt3.setText((r6));

                //Calcula descuento 1%
                float d1 = (s3*1)/100;
                String r7 = String.valueOf((double) d1);
                descuento1.setText((r7));

                //Calcula total descuento
                float tdesc = d21 + d5 + d2 + d1;
                String r8 = String.valueOf((double)
                        tdesc);
                tdescuento.setText((r8));

                //Calcula diezmo neto
                float dneto = s3-d1;
                String r9 = String.valueOf((double)
                        dneto);
                dtotal.setText((r9));

                break;
            case R.id.btnrd:

                String url =
                        "https://xxxxx.com/diezmos.php?nd=" + nd.getText().toString() + "&fd=" + date.getText().toString() +
                                "&db=" + dbruto.getText().toString() + "&sb1=" + dbruto.getText().toString() + "&d1=" + veintiuno.getText().toString() + "&sb2=" + subt1.getText().toString() +
                                "&d2=" + descuento5.getText().toString() + "&sb3=" + subt2.getText().toString() + "&d3=" + descuento2.getText().toString() +
                                "&sb4=" + subt3.getText().toString() + "&d4=" + descuento1.getText().toString() + "&sb5=" + descuento1.getText().toString() +
                                "&td=" + tdescuento.getText().toString() + "&dn="+dtotal.getText().toString();

                jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
                rq.add(jrq);
                break;
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo registrar los datos" + error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha registrado los datos correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        limpiarRegistros();
    }
    private void limpiarRegistros() {
        nd.setText("");
        date.setText("");
        dbruto.setText("");
        veintiuno.setText("");
        subt1.setText("");
        descuento5.setText("");
        subt2.setText("");
        descuento2.setText("");
        subt3.setText("");
        descuento1.setText("");
        tdescuento.setText("");
        dtotal.setText("");
    }
    }
```

Obtuve el resultado esperado, logré 1. que se calculara los datos con el botón calcular diezmos, dado que el Activity trae desde una Activity anterior el dato de diezmo bruto, 2. Que se ingresara los datos en una base de datos externa localizada en phpmyAdmin y que al registrarlos me devolviera los campos vacíos de toda los EditText del Activity. Si a alguien le sirve dejo el archivo php:

```
<?php

$json=array();
    if(isset($_GET["nd"]) && ($_GET["fd"]) &&($_GET["db"]) && ($_GET["sb1"]) && ($_GET["d1"]) && ($_GET["sb2"]) && ($_GET["d2"]) && ($_GET["sb3"]) && ($_GET["d3"]) && ($_GET["sb4"]) && ($_GET["d4"]) && ($_GET["sb5"]) && ($_GET["td"]) && isset($_GET["dn"])){
        $nd = $_GET['nd'];
        $fd = $_GET['fd'];
        $db = $_GET['db'];
        $sb1 = $_GET['sb1'];
        $d1 = $_GET['d1'];
        $sb2 = $_GET['sb2'];
        $d2 = $_GET['d2'];
        $sb3 = $_GET['sb3'];
        $d3 = $_GET['d3'];
        $sb4 = $_GET['sb4'];
        $d4 = $_GET['d4'];
        $sb5 = $_GET['sb5'];
        $td = $_GET['td'];
        $dn = $_GET['dn'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect 
("tulocalhost","tu bd","tu contraseña","tu tabla" ) or die  
("Sin Conexion");

        $consulta="INSERT INTO diezmos(ndom, fdom, dbru, subt1,  
desc21, subt2, desc5, subt3, desc2, subt4, desc1, subt5, tdesc, dneto) 

VALUES  
('{$nd}','{$fd}','{$db}','{$sb1}','{$d1}','{$sb2}','{$d2}','{$sb3}','{$d3}','{$sb4}','{$d4}','{$sb5}','{$td}','{$dn}')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);


        if($consulta){
           $consulta="SELECT * FROM diezmos  WHERE 

ndom='{$nd}'";
           $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

            if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['datos'][]=$reg;
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }



        else{
            $results['nd']='';
            $results['fd']='';
            $results['db']='';
            $results['sb1']='';
            $results['d1']='';
            $results['sb2']='';
            $results['d2']='';
            $results['sb3']='';
            $results['d3']='';
            $results['sb4']='';
            $results['d4']='';
            $results['sb5']='';
            $results['td']='';
            $results['dn']='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }

    }
    else{   
            $results['nd']='';
            $results['fd']='';
            $results['db']='';
            $results['sb1']='';
            $results['d1']='';
            $results['sb2']='';
            $results['d2']='';
            $results['sb3']='';
            $results['d3']='';
            $results['sb4']='';
            $results['d4']='';
            $results['sb5']='';
            $results['td']='';
            $results['dn']='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
?>
```